# How to add gaps between tmux panes?

Tags: terminal, tmux, window-management

Tmux with split panes usually looks like this:

```
|-----------------------|-----------------------|
|                       |                       |
|                       |                       |
|                       |                       |
|                       |                       |
|                       |                       |
|                       |                       |
|                       |                       |
|                       |-----------------------|
|                       |                       |
|                       |                       |
|                       |                       |
|                       |                       |  
|                       |                       |
|                       |                       |
|-----------------------|-----------------------|
```

But would it be possible to make tmux with split panes have gaps like this?

```
|------------------------------------------|
|                 |   |                    |
|                 |   |                    |    
|                 |   |                    |        
|                 |   |                    |
|                 |   |                    |
|                 |   |                    |
|                 |   |--------------------|
|                 |                        |
|                 |   |--------------------|
|                 |   |                    |        
|                 |   |                    |
|                 |   |                    |
|                 |   |                    |
|                 |   |                    |
|------------------------------------------|
```

Other examples:

No gaps:

[image]

With gaps:

[image]

Is this possible with tmux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that's possible with tmux without writing a patch that implements it (which is absolutely possible, but I'm not aware of an existing one).